# PHP Method Chaining setting and getting a value

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently studying OOP Method Chaining, but I'm having difficulties from making it work.

I've created setValue method where it returns a value based on the parameters.

Then, I've created setLabel method and added a parameter to be used after a setValue has been called.

Here is the current code I have:-

```
class Field
{
  public $label;

  public function setValue($property, $value)
  {
    $this->$property = new \stdClass();
    $this->$property->value = $value;
    $this->$property->label = $this->label;

    return $this;
  }

  public function setLabel($label)
  {
    return $this->label = $label;
  }
}
```

A sample code for retrieving the data:-

```
$field = new Field;
$field->setValue('textfield', 'something to print')->setLabel('Label here');
print $field->textfield->value; // Returns the value
print $field->textfield->label; // Returns an empty string
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Please help.

Comment: Calling `setLabel()` only changes `$field->label`, not `$field->textfield->label`. Primitives (like strings) in PHP are passed by value, not reference

Comment: Hi @Phil How can I setLabel in $field->textfield->label? I needed it that way because I will use the $this->label with other method.

Comment: you're setting label of field, not of $property ("textfield")

Comment: Is it the intent that Field only has one label or does each property have a label?

Comment: @ryantxr each property will going to have a different label.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the following is your goal:

```
print $field->textfield->value; // Returns the value
print $field->textfield->label; // Returns the label
```

if you want this to work:

```
$field = new Field;
$field->setValue('textfield', 'something to print')->setLabel('Label here');
```

Then you need to do something like this:

```
class FieldProperty {
    public $label
    public $value;
    public setValue($value) { $this->value = $value; return $this; }
    public setLabel($label) { $this->label = $label; return $this; }

}

class Field
{
    public function setValue($property, $value)
    {
        $this->$property = new FieldProperty();
        $this->$property->setValue($value);
        return $this->$property;
    }
}
```

Thinking about it further, we can add:

```
class Field
{
    public function setValue($property, $value)
    {
        $this->$property = new FieldProperty();
        $this->$property->setValue($value);
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function setProperty($propertyName)
    {
        $this->$propertyName = new FieldProperty;
        return $this->$propertyName;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
$field->setProperty('textfield')->setLabel('my label')->setValue('some value');
```

Comment: OP indicates in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778666/php-method-chaining-setting-and-getting-a-value/48779496#comment84559154_48778666) that they still need `$field->label`

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. Modified my answer.

Comment: Where? Still can't see `public $label` in `Field`

Comment: It is no longer necessary.

Comment: How do you figure? OP clearly says they need to use it

Comment: If you look at `print $field->textfield->label`, it is clear that putting $label in Field is a mistake. It seems clear that each property has its own label. Putting it in Field object means that there can only be one label.

Comment: I agree it's not completely clear what OP wants out of this but I'm just going by their comment that I linked to ~ _"I needed it that way because I will use the `$this->label` with other method"_

Comment: I saw that and my take on it was, no, don't do that because that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a reference between `$this->$property->label` and `$this->label`, [assign the value by reference](http://php.net/manual/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign)

```
$this->$property->label =& $this->label;
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/955943

---

Be warned, the reference works both ways so if you assign a new label to `$field->textfield->label`, it will also change `$field->label`.

I feel a better approach would be to use magic methods to automatically create each *property*. Then you can keep track of them all in a private field and update their labels accordingly.

```
class Field
{
  public $label;

  private $properties = []; // this will store all your dynamic properties

  public function __get($name) {
    // lazily create properties on demand
    if (!isset($this->properties[$name])) {
      $this->properties[$name] = new \stdclass();
    }
    return $this->properties[$name];
  }

  public function setValue($property, $value)
  {
    // this will automatically create "$property" if it's not defined
    $this->$property->value = $value;
    $this->$property->label = $this->label;

    return $this;
  }

  public function setLabel($label)
  {
    // Set the field label and any known property labels
    $this->label = $label;
    foreach($this->properties as $property) {
      $property->label = $label;
    }
    return $label; // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried copy and paste the example code above, but the I don't know why when I'm trying to use it twice with different property and different label, it shows same label.

Like:-

print $obj->setValue('prop1', 'print me')->setLabel('label 1'); // prints label 2
print $obj->setValue('prop2', 'print me2')->setLabel('label 2');  // prints label 2

Comment: @CatherineSalvador Isn't that what you wanted? If not, you'll need to change your question to show **exactly** what you want to happen, particularly if there's more than one _property_ as well as what you expect to happen to `$field->label`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) way, I guess, I need to do it like the following. Create the base `Field` class:

```
class Field
{
    public $value;
    public $label;

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Maybe, even make it [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Then you can extend this class, creating specific fields:

```
final class TextField extends Field
{

}

$textField = (new TextField)
    ->setValue('something to print')
    ->setLabel('Label here');
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1611ff39a9a4e64ec6f7b8e3056ee9edab38b5c0).

This way, you can utilize [**polymorphism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) later in your program. Say you have an object, to which you pass a bunch of different objects of type `Field` (read extend `Field`). Then doing your way, this object wouldn't know what `$property` each of them has, and it wouldn't be able to access `value` and `label` - the objects don't share the common interface. But, with objects, that share the common interface (in our case extend the same base class), we can simply loop over the bunch of fields and retrieve values and labels.

In order to render this fields, the one (read a little bit ugly) solution would be to utilize [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function:

```
switch ($class = get_class($field)) {
    case 'TextField':
        $this->renderTextField($field);
        break;
    case 'InputField':
        $this->renderInputField($field);
        break;

    // ...

    default:
        throw new Exception("Cannot render $class.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `label` property of `$property` (`'textfield'`) not `$this`. It means `var_dump($field->textfield->label);` doesn't contain anything but `var_dump($field->label);` does.

Saying that you need to store `$property`'s name so that later you can refer to it. A quick working solution would be:

```
<?php

class Field
{
  public $label;
  public $propName;

  public function setValue($property, $value)
  {
    $this->propName = $property;
    $this->$property = new \stdClass();
    $this->$property->value = $value;
    $this->$property->label = $this->label;
    return $this;
  }

  public function setLabel($label)
  {
    $this->{$this->propName}->label = $label;
  }
}

$field = new Field;
$field->setValue('textfield', 'something to print')->setLabel('Label here');
var_dump($field->textfield->value, $field->textfield->label);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/DnJTE)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necromance but I wanted to do the same thing but without creating methods for each, while staying nice and short (i didn't want `->setMethod('propertyName', $value)`)

```php
class Field
{
  public function __call($property, $args): self
  {
    $this->{$property} = $args[0];

    return $this;
  }
}
```

Sample use:

```php
$field = (new Field)->label('label!')->value('value!');
```

And the value of `$field`:

```
Field Object
(
  [label] => label!
  [value] => value!
)
```

I also whitelisted what property names I'll allow to be set, and just ignore anything else.

Answer (score -1):

In your code "label" has the value into Field Object and not into textfield object as you can see:

```
 Field object {
      label => (string) Label here
      textfield => stdClass object {
        value => (string) something to print
        label => null
      }
    }
```

You colud use `$field->label`, because they are stored in different object, or  try this:

```
class Field {

  public function setValue($value) {
      $this->property = new \stdClass();
      $this->property->value = $value;
      return $this;
  }

  public function setLabel($label) {
      $this->property->label = $label;
      return $this->property;
  }

}

$field = new Field();
$field->setValue('something to print')->setLabel('Label here');
print $field->property->value;
print $field->property->label;
```

Output

```
something to printLabel here
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I needed to pass the $property parameter in setValue as I am rendering a multiple types of fields.

Comment: Then you  could use $field->label, they are stored in different object as I wrote in my answer.